# Why is variable in prototypal constructor undefined when accessed as a property?

Tags: javascript, variables, prototypal-inheritance

Why is `myPerson.age` undefined?

```js
function Person() {
  var age = 28;
}

var myPerson = new Person();

console.log(myPerson.age);
```

I have clearly set what the varaible is in the `Person` function construtor which should be pointed to by the `.prototype` of `myPerson`, no?

Comment: No, it's just a local variable that will be lost once the constructor returns, unless you capture the entire scope with a nested function...

Comment: `var age` only creates a variable local to the function. It does not set a property to the object returned by `new Person`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Person(){

    this.age = 28;

}


$(document).ready(function(){


  var myPerson = new Person();

  console.log(myPerson.age);


});
```

Comment: Awesome I see now why I need to use 'this' (as it points to the generic object that gets created when I use the new keyword').. thanks :-)